# Coprime powers of an element in a group nullify

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I had the following argument which I wanted to verify:

> If $g_1,...,g_k$ are generators of $G$, and we have the following relations in $G$, $g_1^m=g_1^n=e$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $g_1=e$ in $G$.

I use the following claim for it:

> Let $g\in G$ such that $g^m=e$ and $g^n=e$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $g=e$.

My 'proof' goes as follows:

Denote $p=O_G(g)$. Then $p\mid n$ and $p\mid m$, and since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ this implies that $p=1$.

Since I am not that sure when it comes to group theory, I wanted to know whether this line of reasoning seems valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. Of course you need to justify that the order of $g_1$ divides $m$ and $n$.

Another way is to
use the Euclidean algorithm to find integers $r$ and $s$ such that $rm+sn=1$.
Then, writing $g=g_1$ we have
$$
g=g^1=g^{rm+sn}=(g^m)^r(g^n)^s=e.
$$